# opencart 1.4.9.3 mysql unknown column error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join, opencart

I'm using opencart 1.4.9.3 version. I have downloaded the banner manager from here http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=4886 . I follwed that installation steps.

When I click `EXTENSIONS > BANNERS` it returns this error

```
Error: Unknown column 'jo_bts.store_id' in 'field list'
Error No: 1054
SELECT jo_bts.store_id, s.name FROM jo_banner_to_store bts LEFT JOIN jo_store s ON s.store_id = bts.store_id WHERE banner_id = 1 ORDER BY store_id
```

But In my database table I have `store_id` column

**jo_banner** table

[image]

**jo_banner_to_store** table

[image]

```
public function getBannerStores($banner_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT " . DB_PREFIX . "bts.store_id, s.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "banner_to_store bts LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "store s ON s.store_id = bts.store_id WHERE banner_id = " . (int) $banner_id . " ORDER BY store_id");
        return $query->rows;
    }
```

Comment: I have one little OT question: it is OpenCart 1.5.6.4 out now while OC 1.5.0 was released more than two years ago. Why to exhaust resources on such old system instead of using them to upgrade your store to newest version? OC 1.4.9.x was great (for that time) but since 1.5.x lot of new features and bugs were fixed. For me, OC 1.4.9 equals to IE 7 - sooner or later there will be nobody to support it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the given query you are using undefined **alias jo_bts** and i guess where  the alias is defined the creator of has not used the table prefix,change `bts` to `" . DB_PREFIX . "bts`

```
public function getBannerStores($banner_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT " . DB_PREFIX . "bts.store_id, s.name 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "banner_to_store " . DB_PREFIX . "bts 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "store s 
         ON s.store_id = " . DB_PREFIX . "bts.store_id WHERE banner_id = " . (int) $banner_id . "
         ORDER BY store_id");
        return $query->rows;
    }
```

So final query will look like

```
SELECT 
  jo_bts.store_id,
  s.name 
FROM
  jo_banner_to_store jo_bts 
  LEFT JOIN jo_store s 
    ON s.store_id = jo_bts.store_id 
WHERE banner_id = 1 
ORDER BY store_id
```

Comment: still same error `Unknown column 'bts.store_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @Beginner see my answer again i was updating the on clause part